# upload an image in php

Tags: php, upload

I have this code to upload an image :

```
$name = "test.jpg";
if (isset($_FILES['image']))
{
        if ($_FILES['image']['size'] <= 500000)
        {
                $extensions_ok = array( 'jpg' , 'jpeg' , 'gif' , 'png' );
                $extension_upload = strtolower(  substr(  strrchr($_FILES['image']['name'], '.')  ,1)  );
                if (in_array($extension_upload,$extensions_ok))
                {
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$name);
                }

        }

}
```

it's working with some picture, but with other it doesn't work (even when the size is less than 5mo)
for an example, it's working with this one :[image]

but not with this one :[image]

Comment: Increase the maximum size post in php.ini

Comment: Does the server have a post size limit smaller than your manual check?

Comment: Thomas im working in local, @KA_lin should i edit php.ini-development or php.ini-production ?

Comment: does your second image contain dot in filename? =)

Comment: did you try to debug on what step second image fail to upload?